# Combine 2 collections (keep the similar ones)

Tags: php, laravel, collections, intersection

I've several collections, I want to keep only the elements that are present in each collection.

I went through the available methods, but I didn't find anything that would match.

```
$candidatesByConsultant = Consultant::find(request('consultant_id'))->candidates;
$candidatesByCreation = Candidate::whereBetween('created_at',[Carbon::parse(request('meeting_since')), Carbon::parse(request('meeting_to'))])->get();
```

Do you have any idea? :)

Comment: Have you tried "intersect"?

Comment: Do you want to process the collections to find common elements or have a sql query with the conditions?

Comment: Do you want candidates that are present only in both collections at the same time? Then use intersect as @Amarnasan suggested.

Comment: Why don't you try this?
$candidates=Candidate::where('consultant_id',request('consultant_id'))->whereBetween('created_at',[Carbon::parse(request('meeting_since')), Carbon::parse(request('meeting_to'))])->get();

Comment: Yes, intersect works perfectly, thx a lot guys!

Answer (score 1):

In order to have values that only present in both collection you must use intersect method:

```
$result = $candidatesByConsultant->intersect($candidatesByCreation);
```

The intersect method intersects the values of both collections. You can read it in Laravel's official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-intersect).

And in order to get have results that are not present in both collection you must use diff method:

```
$result = $candidatesByConsultant->diff($candidatesByCreation);
```

The diff method finds differences between collections. You can read it in Laravel's official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-diff).

Answer (score 0):

The `intersect` method may be suitable : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-intersect

Example taken from the documentation:

```php
$collection = collect(['Desk', 'Sofa', 'Chair']);

$intersect = $collection->intersect(['Desk', 'Chair', 'Bookcase']);

$intersect->all();

// [0 => 'Desk', 2 => 'Chair']
```

However, especially if you are trying to intersect multiple collections of **Eloquent models**, it may not work since the equality between two models is defined by the Model::is() method. Check 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#comparing-models for more information about comparing two Eloquent models.

To handle this, I would do the following, assuming the primary key of your models is `id`:

```php
$candidatesByConsultant = Consultant::find(request('consultant_id'))->candidates;
$candidatesByCreation = Candidate::whereBetween('created_at',[Carbon::parse(request('meeting_since')), Carbon::parse(request('meeting_to'))])->get();

$candidates = $candidatesByConsultant->merge($candidatesByCreation)->unique("id");
```

You may check the [merge()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-merge) and [unique()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-unique) documentations.

Comment: Unique over the merged sets will also return values that are only in one set.

Comment: I was also thinking about that but since unique uses the equality ==, it may not work properly while comparing two Eloquent models (source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#comparing-models)

Comment: That's not what I mean. The OP is asking for a solution that yields a collection which contains all models that are present in both input collections. I.e. `[a, b, c] + [a, c, f] = [a, c]` -- Your solution will yield a collection which contains all models of both input collections, but each model only once (no duplicates). I.e. `[a, b, c] + [a, c, f] = [a, b, c, f]`

Comment: Correct, I was narrow focused, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in for this is `$collection->intersect($other)`, but you can also achieve the desired result with a simple custom filter:

```
$left  = collect([Model::find(1), Model::find(2), Model::find(3)]);
$right = collect([Model::find(1), Model::find(3), Model::find(5)]);

$result = $left->filter(function ($value, $key) use ($right) {
    return $right->contains(function ($v, $k) use ($value) {
        return $v->id === $value->id;
    });
});
```

This will perform model comparison by `id`. It is not very performant though. Another approach would be to retrieve two arrays of `ids`, intersect them and filter the merged sets based on this list:

```
$left   = collect([Model::find(1), Model::find(2), Model::find(3)]);
$right  = collect([Model::find(1), Model::find(3), Model::find(5)]);
$merged = $left->merge($right);

$ids = array_intersect($left->pluck('id')->toArray(), $right->pluck('id')->toArray());

$result = $merged->filter(function ($value, $key) use ($ids) {
    return in_array($value->id, $ids);
});
```